# Como exibir um elemento a partir de um true ou false dentro do Objeto? Javascript ReactJs

Tags: javascript, react

eu tenho um array de objetos, e eu quero exibir o `value` a partir de seu `status` que é um atributo dentro do objeto.

```js
this.state = {
  objetcs: [{
    value: 1,
    status: false
  }, {
    value: 2,
    status: true
  }]
}
}

// const object = [{ value: 1, status: false }, {value: 2, status: true} ]
```

Se o `status` for `true` eu renderizo ele, se náo, não renderizo.

Como posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar `.filter` para filtrar o `state` e depois mapear para o JSX que precisares.
<sub>Repara que no teu states tens objects escrito *objetcs*, eu corrigi no exemplo em baixo</sub>

```js
class Componente extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      objects: [{
        value: 0,
        status: true
      }, {
        value: 1,
        status: false
      }, {
        value: 2,
        status: true
      }]
    }
  }

  render() {
    const activeElements = this.state.objects
      .filter(obj => obj.status)
      .map(obj => (<p>{obj.value}</p>));
    return (<div>{activeElements}</div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <Componente/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```